# Unity resolves last registration when class registered with multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

```
public interface A
{
}
public interface B
{
}
public interface C : A, B
{
}
public class Foo : C
{
}
        IUnityContainer unity = new UnityContainer();
        unity.RegisterType<A, Foo>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(container => { throw new Exception(); }));
        unity.RegisterType<B, Foo>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(container => { throw new Exception(); }));
        unity.Resolve<A>(); //uses RegisterType<B, Foo> InjectionFactory
```

I expected Unity to use "A" InjectionFactory.

Comment: Interesting and I'd say it is a bug or at least doesn't work as expected. Using named registrations seems to resolve the issue however this could be not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity only maintains one build plan per build key so the second registration is overwriting the first registration (for Foo).

When registering, first a mapping is created between A and Foo and second it applies any injection members to the target type (Foo) based on the build key (Type: Foo, Name: null).

So, the mapping between A and Foo is separate from the injection members applied to Foo.

To illustrate more clearly the overwriting of the registration, I believe that the following is functionally equivalent to your configuration:

```
unity.RegisterType<Foo>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionFactory(container => { throw new Exception(); }));

unity.RegisterType<Foo>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionFactory(container => { throw new Exception(); }));

unity.RegisterType<A, Foo>();
```

In general, if you need different injection members applied to the same concrete type then you will need to use named registrations.